# How to draw a line in c# console app without using any pre defined methods

Tags: c#, .net, console

Can someone write a function to draw line in c# console app without any predefined methods?

Line needs to be drawn using 'o' character.

Input is x1, y1 and x2, y2

Two points are given and need to draw line from point a to b

TIA

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo");`

Comment: define _predefined methods_ - `Console.WriteLine` is a predefined method aswell

Comment: @micheal  please see my post. Edited need to draw line from point a to point b

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Bresenham's line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm)

Here is a adoption [All cases covered Bresenham's line-algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11678693/all-cases-covered-bresenhams-line-algorithm)